# How to increase List View threshold in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, count, onedrive, powershell-4.0

I have a very large SharePoint folder with many nested subfolder and I'm trying to count how many items are in there before we migrate that folder to different location.

I've this simple script but I'm always getting this error when every I tried to count a folder that really large so just wondering how can I increase the threshold or fix this issue.

```
$SiteURL = "https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/hello_nam_corp_com"
$searchfor  = "/Documents/Archive"
$folderpath = "Documents/Archive"
$CSVFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\Resource\FolderStats.csv"

#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -useWebLogin
      
#Get the list
#$documents = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq 'Documents'}

$FolderItems = Get-PnpListItem -List $folderpath

$fieldvalues = $FolderItems.Fieldvalues

$result = @()
foreach ($field in $fieldvalues) {
    $obj = New-object psobject -property $field 
    $result += $obj.fileref
}

$final = $result | where-object {$_ -match $searchfor}

$item = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    FolderName     = Split-Path -Path $searchfor -Leaf 
    URL            = $searchfor 
    filesfoldercount = $final.count
}

$item 
$item  |  Export-Csv -Path $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

```
Get-PnpListItem : The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.
At line:13 char:16
+ $FolderItems = Get-PnpListItem -List $folderpath
```

Comment: Does [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/576522/getting-34the-attempted-operation-is-prohibited-be.html) answer your question?

Comment: It look like it might work but the issue I have is I only want to get an items count from a  specific folder(just one folder) under Document List. Not the whole folders under Document.

Comment: have you tried this: Get-PnPListItem -List listname -FolderServerRelativeUrl "/sites/contosomarketing/Lists/lists/folder

Answer (score 0):

Try below PowerShell.

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing"
$ListName = "Branding"
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\FolderStats.csv"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -Interactive
  
#Get the list
$List = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName
 
#Get Folders from the Library - with progress bar
$global:counter = 0
$FolderItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500 -Fields FileLeafRef -ScriptBlock { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete `
            ($global:Counter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Getting Items from List:" -Status "Processing Items $global:Counter to $($List.ItemCount)";}  | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder"}
Write-Progress -Activity "Completed Retrieving Folders from List $ListName" -Completed
 
$FolderStats = @()
#Get Files and Subfolders count on each folder in the library
ForEach($FolderItem in $FolderItems)
{
    #Get Files and Folders of the Folder
    Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $FolderItem.Folder -Property Files, Folders | Out-Null
     
    #Collect data
    $Data = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
        FolderName     = $FolderItem.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
        URL            = $FolderItem.FieldValues.FileRef
        FilesCount     = $FolderItem.Folder.Files.Count
        SubFolderCount = $FolderItem.Folder.Folders.Count
    }
    $Data
    $FolderStats+= $Data
}
#Export the data to CSV
$FolderStats | Export-Csv -Path $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Script Link: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/05/sharepoint-online-get-files-sub-folders-count-in-document-library-using-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

A little late to help you but still worth mentioning that you can add the PageSize parameter to return results in pages of the designated size:

```
Get-PnPListItem -List Tasks -PageSize 1000
```

In your example you would add this here:

```
$FolderItems = Get-PnpListItem -List $folderpath -PageSize 1000
```

More info here:
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPListItem.html